# Oracle SQL statement for one to many to append the multiple records (fields) to one string

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am writing a SQL statement for Oracle where there is a one to many relationship between two tables. The table Person has a foreign key to table Purchase which has a Purchase Description field.

I need to write a SELECT query that will take all the purchase records/rows and append them to each other like so

Person Table

```
PersonID  PersonName
1               John
```

Purchases Table

```
PurchaseId (PK), PersonID(FK), PurchaseDescription
1                           1                     Book
2                           1                     Clothes
3                           1                     Bag
4                           1                     Dinner
```

So the output of the query would look like this

Output = 1, Book:Bag:Clothes:Dinner

The output will be one row from the one to many relationship where there are separate records for book, bag, clothes, and dinner.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `wm_concat()`, or `ListAgg()` (if 10g or newer)

Answer (score 0):

to do this use a function called [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030), like this

```
SELECT 'Output = '||CAST(P.PersonID AS VARCHAR(100)), LISTAGG(Pur.PurchaseDescription, ':')
FROM Person P
LEFT JOIN Purchase Pur ON P.PersonID = Pur.PersonID
GROUP BY P.PersonID
```